# Given $n_o \in \mathbb N$ , are there only finitely many rationals in the interval , such that denominator in reduced form does not exceed $n_o$?

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that , given $n_o \in \mathbb N$ for any real $a,b$ with $0 \le a < b$  , there are only finitely many rationals $x \in (a,b)$ such that $x=m/n$ , g.c.d. $(m,n)=1$ , and $0<n \le n_0$ ?

Comment: Forget about the $\gcd (m,n) = 1$ condition and show that there are only finitely many pairs $(m,n)$ of integers, $0 < n \leqslant n_0$ such that $\frac{m}{n} \in (a,b)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : How to show that there are only finitely many $m$ ?

Comment: According to the timestamps, you thought about Daniel's comment for at most two minutes before admitting defeat. I suggest that you think about it for an hour or so before asking for more help.

Answer (score 1):

The rational numbers of the form $\frac{a}{N}$ with $\gcd(a,N)=1$ in the interval $(0,1)$ are exactly $\varphi(N)$,
so the number of rational numbers in $(0,1)$ with a denominator $\leq N_0$ are given by:

$$ \sum_{N=2}^{N_0} \varphi(N) \approx \frac{3}{\pi^2} N_0^2, $$
see [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence).

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, assume that m is an integer. Then all we have to do is show that for any value of n such that $0 < n \le n_0$, *m* must lie within a fixed range.

$x = \frac{m}{n}$ and $x \in (a,b)$, then

$a \le \frac{m}{n} \le b$

which implies,

$an \le m \le bn$

And as *m* is an integer, therefore only a finite number of values of *m* is possible within this range *(an, bn)*, excluding also values which are not coprime with *n*. Also note that there is only a finite number of possible values of n as well.
Hence there is only a finite number of rationals of the form $\frac{m}{n}$ with the range *(a,b)* under the given conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There are clearly only finitely many denominators between 1 and $n_{0}$. For each of these denominators $n$ the numerator must be at least $a n$ and no smaller than $b n$.